# Deno run is not working properly also drun

Tags: deno

After created an index.ts and wrote a simple code for listening to port 3000 and printing hello world on the body, I'm also not able to run or get the output from deno's **drun** module.

```
import { Application, Router } from "https://deno.land/x/denotrain@v0.5.0/mod.ts";

const app = new Application();

const router = new Router();

// Middleware 
app.use((ctx) => {

  ctx.cookies["user.session"] = "qwertz";
  ctx.cookies["a"] = "123";
  ctx.cookies["b"] = "456";
  delete ctx.cookies["user.session"];
  return;
});

router.get("/", (ctx) => {

  return new Promise((resolve) => resolve("This is the admin interface!")); 
});
router.get("/edit", async (ctx) => {
  return "This is an edit mode!"; 
});

app.get("/", (ctx) => {

  return {"hello": "world"};
});

app.use("/admin", router);

app.get("/:id", (ctx) => {
  // Use url parameters
  return "Hello World with ID: " + ctx.req.params.id
});

  return ctx.req.body;
});

await app.run()
```

[image]

Comment: what output are you getting when you run it? What command are you using to run the srever?

Comment: And btw the code you posted has a Syntax Error.

Comment: deno run --allow-net index.ts is the command i wrote to run the app

Comment: i used drun to run the app but no use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Development Environment:- Windows 10

The problem seems to be the address **0.0.0.0** is specific to **mac** only.Windows Doesn't use **0.0.0.0** address.

After going to **localhost:3000 / 127.0.0.1:3000**. I was able to get the output.I think maybe Windows redirects the **0.0.0.0** to localhost. Anyway it solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

I am on windows. I faced with the same problem. Then,

```
const app = new Application({hostname:"127.0.0.1"});
```

I created the app in typescript giving parameter hostname like above.
And run deno like this:

```
deno run --allow-net=127.0.0.1 index.ts
```

it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Run your server with the following command:

```
drun watch --entryPoint=./server.ts --runtimeOptions=--allow-net
```

---

In any case most Deno tools for watching changes are still bugged, I recommend to use `nodemon`, with `--exec` flag

```
nodemon --exec deno run --allow-net server.ts
```

For convenience you can use `nodemon.json` with the following content:

```
{
  "execMap": {
    "js": "deno run --allow-net",
    "ts": "deno run --allow-net"
  },
  "ext": "js,json,ts"
}
```

And now just use:  `nodemon server.ts`

Comment: I tried the drun command you posted earlier still no result.But Showing the Serving on the http://0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: The app by default uses `3000` show where you're setting port: `8000`

Comment: If you run it without `drun` or `nodemon` does it work, just `deno run -A server.ts`?

Comment: Sorry i used 3000.I change to 8000 if its the problem of port but not.

Comment: After running the deno run command it still show the same error i showed above. Nothing gets displayed.

Comment: So you see: `Showing the Serving on the 0.0.0.0:8000` and nothing else? No error on the terminal?.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214415/discussion-between-patrick-prakash-and-marcos-casagrande).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an error in your code snippet, with the last

```
  return ctx.req.body;
});
```

If you fix that and use the last deno (v1.0.1) and drun(v1.1.0) versions it should works with the following command:
`drun --entryPoint=index.ts --runtimeOptions=--allow-net`