# How to check Deno installed correctly in my computer?

Tags: deno

I installed Deno using  `iwr https://deno.land/x/install/install.ps1 -useb | iex` this command. I checked installation using:

```
deno --version
```

this command, even though, in my visual studio code Terminal, I run `deno --version` it's working properly, but if I start to run my `.js` File, it is not working.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: You are using Windows, so try using `.\server.js` instead of `./server.js`

Comment: Still, I got the same error

Comment: if you installed it from VS Code terminal, try to close, reopen VS code?

Comment: I reopen it, I got  console message but my port 3000 is not working

Comment: did you run your app with `--allow-net` permission?

Comment: `deno run --allow-net --allow-read --allow-write ./server.js` this is my compile code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deno is installed correctly as you can see by running `deno --version`.

Your script is not working because that's a known bug introduced in version `1.0.3`, try updating to the latest Deno version, `1.0.5` or downgrading to `1.0.0`

See this issue: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/6022

---

Depending on what version you choose, you'll have to use a different version of `Oak` instead of pulling from master, which is considered a bad practice.

For `1.0.0` you'll have to use `Oak 4.0.0`

```
import { Application } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak@v4.0.0/mod.ts'
```

---

> I see the console output, but if I open localhost:3000 , this is not
>   working

On windows you may have to use `127.0.0.1/localhost` as `hostname`.

```
app.listen({ hostname: '127.0.0.1', port })
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61953863/1119863

Comment: I uploaded to Deno version `1.0.0`  but My Localhost does not work

Comment: Please explain what is "My Localhost" does not work, do you see any errors?

Comment: Also check updated answer, use a specific version of `Oak`

Comment: I see the console output, but if I open https://localhost:3000/ , this is not working

Comment: Check updated answer, for windows use `127.0.0.1` has  `hostname`, or `localhost`, otherwise is being bound to `0.0.0.0` and that does not work on Windows. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61953863/1119863